# How i can change template before apply to control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need create a template and apply this to control.
I have the template:

```
private string template = "<ControlTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' x:Key=\"simpleSlider\" TargetType=\"{x:Type Slider}\">"
         + "<Border SnapsToDevicePixels=\"true\" BorderBrush=\"{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}\" BorderThickness=\"{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}\">"
            + "<Grid>"
                + "<Grid.RowDefinitions>"
                    + "<RowDefinition Height=\"Auto\"/>"
                    + "<RowDefinition Height=\"Auto\" MinHeight=\"{TemplateBinding MinHeight}\"/>"
                    + "<RowDefinition Height=\"Auto\"/>"
                + "</Grid.RowDefinitions>"
                + "<Rectangle x:Name=\"PART_SelectionRange\"/>"
                + "<Track x:Name=\"PART_Track\" Grid.Row=\"1\">"
                    + "<Track.Thumb>"
                        + "<Thumb x:Name=\"Thumb\">"
                            + "<Thumb.Template>"
                                + "<ControlTemplate TargetType=\"Thumb\">"
                                    + "<Grid Name=\"grid\">"
                                        + "<Rectangle x:Name=\"slideRec\" Fill=\"Red\" Stroke=\"Black\" StrokeThickness=\"1\" Width=\"10\" Height=\"18\" SnapsToDevicePixels=\"True\"/>"
                                        + "<Label Content=\"{Binding Tag}\" Height=\"16\"/>"
                                    + "</Grid>"
                                + "</ControlTemplate>"
                            + "</Thumb.Template>"
                        + "</Thumb>"
                    + "</Track.Thumb>"
                + "</Track>"
            + "</Grid>"
        + "</Border>"
    + "</ControlTemplate>";
```

And i need programmatically create a control and apply the template to control.
The code is:

```
        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.ValueChanged += slider_ValueChanged;
        slider.Tag = sliders.Count == 0 ? 0 : calcularPosicao(sliders, result);
        slider.Template = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(this.template);
        slider.ApplyTemplate();
```

How can i change the color fill of rectangle?
To try find de rectangle in template I try this:

```
var track = (Track)slider.Template.FindName("PART_Track", slider);
```

But the result is null.

Comment: while I am sure there will be a way to do it programatically, why cant the value be changed prior to even parsing it through the reader. Or is the assigning of the color done somewhere else?

Comment: Note by the way I when I run through the code  the FindName does work and returns a Track. If you are looking for the the Rectangle you should be looking for PART_SelectionRange. Unless you are looking for the slideRec rectangle within the thumb.

Comment: @TYY I'm looking to slideRec.
You run the code FindName next 'slider.ApplyTemplate();' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to do. The problem is that at the time you get to track/ thumb control the control template that you have added has not been applied, to do what you are trying to do you would have to call `applytemplate()` to get the rectangle you are looking for.

```
 var slider = new Slider();
 slider.Template = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(template);
 slider.ApplyTemplate();
 var track = (Track)slider.Template.FindName("PART_Track", slider);
 var thumb = (Thumb)(track.FindName("Thumb") );
 thumb.ApplyTemplate(); // key here
 var rect = (Rectangle)thumb.Template.FindName("slideRec", thumb);
 rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```